# Visually determine pole from Bode plot

Tags: ltspice, bode-plot

[image: Frequency response of amplifier]

Currently I'm taking a basic electronics course and this was a part of homework. The Bode plot represents the frequency response of an amplifier and from this plot we had to determine the dominant pole. I got the answer right (7 MHz) but I guess there was some tolerance in the answers.

How can I visually determine the pole within 1 MHz from a Bode plot like this?

Where is the pole when there isn't a sharp angle at the wanted frequency?

Comment: I don't see how you determined it is 7 MHz. What definition you used to determine it is at 7 MHz?

Comment: It took the frequency that was in the middle of the curvature near the dominant pole. You could call it guesswork

Comment: So you must do homework without being told at class how to do it, i.e. how a pole affects the amplitude and phase, when approximating Bode plots?

Comment: No, I know how much the amplitude and phase shifts at a pole. I'm more curious if there is a way to tell it from the plot visually. If I draw a bode plot for a simple transfer function manually I get sharp corners at poles/zeros so they're easy to determine visually.

Comment: Where does the amplitude fall off by 3 dB?

Comment: But is the -3dB point the same as the dominant pole?

Comment: But what do the sharp corners approximate? If you have as simple RC filter, what is the simplified bode plot sharp corner approximating? What is the phase shift at sharp corner?

Comment: The 3 dB point and 90 degree phase change don't at all properly coincide hence no, it's guesswork.

Comment: The sharp corners approximate the cutoff-frequency and the phase shift is 90deg

Comment: @Andyaka 3 dB and 45 \$^\circ\$?

Comment: Yes, my bad. 45deg/dec. So to conclude this there isn't a way to determine it visually from this plot?

Comment: @Andyaka No they don't but it's the 45 degree phase change you should be looking at.

Comment: @Mark, no not 45deg/dec. The -3 dB point should be close to the 45 deg phase shift point. Is it? What is the frequency?

Comment: @Mark And for the RC filter, what is the actual attenuation at cut-off point? If you assume that your plot above is from a simple RC filter, could you spot the cut-off point, by using attenuation and phase change?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy no I mean the 90 degree point - that's the phase shift that a signal undergoes in a 2nd order filter at resonance from DC. Just look at the graph.

Comment: @Justme no I mean the 90 degree point - that's the phase shift that a signal undergoes in a 2nd order filter at resonance from DC.  Just look at the graph.

Comment: @Both of you - It's a clearly a shelving filter and therefore more complex than just a simple second order filter - look at the amplitude response. All bets are off if the filter is unknown and there are anomalies when making simple assumptions.

Comment: @Andyaka The slope is 6dB per octave. How is that a 2nd order system? True, it is a shelving filter of some sorts so it's not simple.

Comment: It’s not a simple second order filter. It’s more complex.

Comment: The pole and the zero are close (a decade or so) and influence each other, that's why you can't rely on the 3 dB point. You also can't rely on the phase because the effect of the zero starts well before the phase turns 90 deg. But if, as you say, some "tolerance" is allowed, then go with the 3 dB point and the dominant pole's frequency will be *around* that point.